# Grab value from unrelated object where two fields match

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have two objects - "Account" and "Appointment". I'm trying to pull the value of the field "Status" from the "Appointment" object where "Account.Initial_Date" matches "Appointment.Date_Time". I initially tried making a new field in the "Account" object to return a text field and see if maybe it would return the first value:

```
Appointment__c.Status__c
```

Which results in the error:

> "Field Appointment__c does not exist. Check spelling."

I was told that it's too difficult to link from "Appointment" to "Account" because there can be multiple appointments per account, which is why I'm trying to link based on the date fields. My next attempt was using `VLOOKUP`, but I read that this only works between custom objects, and I think I'm working with standard objects here... what kind of solution should I be looking for?

Adding the tag [apex](/questions/tagged/apex) here in case this can **only** be achieved via a script of some sort - if that's the case, I'll make attempt via that.

Answer (score 1):

> I was told that it's too difficult to link from "Appointment" to "Account" because there can be multiple appointments per account

This is incorrect. That relationship appears to be exactly the same as that between Contact and Account - one Contact, many Accounts. It's a very common relationship pattern in Salesforce.

If an Appointment is logically related to an Account, it should have a relationship field referencing the Account object to which it is related.

However, having a one-to-many relationship does not mean you can trivially represent specific data points from the many side to the one side. The native tool to do so is the Roll-Up Summary Field, but it does not apply to your use case.

There's really three ways to implement your objective, which is essentially implementing a variant of a roll-up summary. `VLOOKUP()`, which works only in Validation Rules, does not apply here.

1. Write two Apex triggers (one on Account and one on Appointment) to react to all changes that would influence what value should appear in the `Account__c.Status__c` field.
2. Write equivalent Process and Flow declarative automation, which *cannot* get 100% of the way there because Process Builder and Flow cannot react to delete events.
3. Use the free and open source [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) application to define a roll-up summary. DLRS can populate a field from the child object (Appointment) to the parent (Account) based on a sorting by another field (`Date_Time__c`).